# how to know which activity was executed last

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I have two activities that use the same intent filter receiver with the same priority lets say activity1 and activity2.
Each page takes me through an intent to different two other activities extending the IntentService, activity1-->activityA and activity2-->activityB.
When they're set on those two new pages activityX gets triggered and after that it should take me back to my original page.
In which case activityX doesn't know if i came from activityA or activityB.

how shall I solve this issue... any advice..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used DeepLinkingActivity to figure out which activity was running last

```
public Integer isAppInThisClass(Context ctx) {
    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) ctx.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> services = activityManager.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

    if (services.size() > 0 && services.get(0).topActivity.getClassName().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("com.example.example.example.activityA")) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (services.size() > 0 && services.get(0).topActivity.getClassName().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("com.example.example.example.activityB")) {
        return 2;
    }
    return 3;
}
```

it worked just fine.

Comment: This is interesting. I will try.